# get the value of radio button and then proceed to autosuggest

Tags: jquery

hello
  i have developed an autosuggest in my site and it works fine and now the problem is now an user selects an radio button the autosuggest should go to corresponding suggestion

```
$().ready(function() {

$("#q").autocomplete('?h=sugg&a='+$("#rad").val(), {
    width:350,
    max: 10,
    highlight: false,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300,
    selectFirst: false,
    formatResult: function(data, value) {
        return value.split(".")[0];
    }

});
<input name="q"   id="q" autocomplete="off"  />
      <input type="radio" name="rad" value="radio" id="rad_0" checked="checked"  />
      Radio</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rad" value="radio1" id="rad_1" />
      Radio</label>
```

the thing is it always selects the default value it does not change if i select the other please tell me how can i do that...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with how you are initializing the autocomplete plugin.

```
$("#q").autocomplete('?h=sugg&a='+$("#rad").val(), ...
```

1. You are using a static value for the source URL. When the radio button changes, it will the URL will not be updated. This will look like: ?h=sugg&a=radio
2. The radio button selector is looking for an object with ID of "rad". You do not have an element with this ID and even if you did it would map to a single radio button.

You can find the selected radio value this way:

```
$("input[name=rad]:checked").val();
```

This will find all input elements with the name "rad" (you have two). It will use the :checked pseudo-selector to only find the checked radio button.

Now, even if you update your initialization to use the new selector, you will still only use the first radio button. Two suggestions:

1. When the radio buttons change, update the autocomplete source.

   $("input[name=rad]").click( function () {
       $("#q").autocomplete("option", "source", "?h=sugg&a=" + this.value);
   });
2. Use a callback source instead. Here you can provide a function at initialization time that can be used to make different queries based on current option values (or whichever criteria you need). More examples of how to use "source" are available [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#option-source).

Full documentation for the autocomplete plugin is [available here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) as well.